# get() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given :Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently making a simple get/post api with django 3. After i run the server and go to the employee/article/ url it return an error

VIEW.PY

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from .models import employees
from .serializer import employeeSerializer

class employeeList(APIView):
    def get(self):
        employess1 = employees.objects.all()
        serializer = employeeSerializer(employess1 ,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import employees

class employeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = employees
        fields = ['first_name','last_name','salary']
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
```

from . import views
urlpatterns = [

```
path('employees/',views.employeeList.as_view()),
```

]

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `request` argument in the `get` method. See the docs [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/)

```
class employeeList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        employess1 = employees.objects.all()
        serializer = employeeSerializer(employess1 ,many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```